Water Leak in Condo through neighbors Condo
We live in a condo building, two units per building. Our water line flows through our neighbors condo. We have a leak, which is determined to be under their living room floor. An excavator has trenched out 4 feet to determine the leak, the space is right next to the neighbors condo and full of water. All our plumbers said this won't hurt our neighbors condo or slab or foundation. Is this true???
Also we have chosen to run a new line from the water pit to our home, thus eliminating the  water going through the neighbors condo. The plumber can do the work within one day. We think this is a good solution, would you agree?
Thanks for your answer.

Where you are located is important. If in Florida the repairs would be under the direction of the condo board.  So you would not have a say in how or what is done.

yes, I agree that you think it is a good solution

Is this true? ... is what true? ... that all your plumbers said the same thing?

Water for a short period of time will not hurt/damage concrete, but the dampest might cause mold to grow.  Being in a condo/neighbour, you yourself probably do not have the final/only say in what repairs are done/allowed.
